# Swift memory management hole: boundary case, feature or bug?

Tags: xml, parsing, memory, swift

Perhaps this will save somebody an hour or several of debugging time. Implementing an XML parser in Swift, analogous to Objective-C, seems simple enough:

```
private class Customparser : NSObject,NSXMLParser
{
    // ... implement the parser protocol methods
}

...

let parser=NSXMLParser(data:data)
parser.delegate=CustomParser()
let success=parser.parse()
```

This code fails with really unhelpful runtime errors (bad access).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the main problem is that assigning to the parser.delegate property directly triggers the automatic reference counting deallocation immediately, because it's an 'assign' property. So if the reader is attached to a different object instance, it lives long enough to actually perform its task:

```
let reader=CustomParser()
let parser=NSXMLParser(data:data)
parser.delegate=reader
let success=parser.parse()
```

In hindsight it's hard to say if it's a bug, because it is consistent with how the underlying Objective-C framework behaves, but it would sure seem that way to someone starting out with Swift.

There's another problem though: declaring the parser class as private does not cause any compiler errors, but it brings back the runtime crash. Taking out the private modifier solves the problem. Does this mean that private classes are compiled in a way that means they can't be handed off to other codeblocks?

Comment: I would open a radar (bugreport.apple.com) about the crash. The compiler should be able to detect that `parser.delegate=CustomParser()` is not valid (because the fact that `CustomParser` conforms to the required protocol is private, and so should not be visible to `NSXMLParser`). Fixing it in the compiler may be difficult, but it is a reasonable thing to request. As for the memory management, that is an error on your part (you never hold a strong reference), but it may be reasonable to expect the static analyzer to detect this kind of bug. A radar might be justified.